Reliable way to tell server-side whether request is originating from within Safe App iFrame
We are listed as a Safe App with https://drips.network/. The way we currently implement the "auto-connects to safe" requirement is by detecting whether our app is running in an iFrame client-side, and then simply pushing the user from our landing page to /app, which initiates some logic that attempts connecting to the Safe provider.
That works fine, except the landing page is visible for about a second before the client-side "redirect" is initiated, which is a bit ugly.
For that reason, I now want to implement a proper 301 redirect to /app server-side when the user hits the root path from within the Safe App iFrame only. Question is: How can I tell if that's the case? Is there maybe some custom header that would make it 100% clear that the user is browsing from within a Safe?
